# Is it possible to set the number of entries HUD returns?

Tags: hud

I would like the HUD to return at least ten entries. Can I do that somehow?

(use case: in Texmaker, I can have ten different user tags - I do not remember their names, so I would like to display all (after typing user tag), but HUD now shows only five)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems from my investigation that this is not (yet) possible in Unity's HUD.